# (CSS) skew img frame without distorting image

Tags: html, css, skew

I'm making a website that contains many skewed elements, like this:

[image]

This isn't too bad, there are CSS transforms that could skew it. But how about this:

[image]

The image isn't distorted, just the frame is cropped in a skewed way. What's the easiest/best way to do this?

Comment: Can you use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [this](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/eZKxNa) should work for you. As a Mark commented on, `clip-path` is a nice way to go. There are tools for getting just the right path such as [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/). Once you've got the path, you drop it right into your code. In my demo, I used it on the `div` wrapping the image, rather than on the image itself. I did it this way to keep border effects—added via pseudo-class—on top of the image.

[image]

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/eZKxNa

Comment: This looks great. The only catch is clip-path is only supported for 69.91% of users (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Comment: @Mirror318 In mid 2020, support is at 94.3%.

Comment: Late 2021, support is at 97.47%.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the following. It creates a skewed parent, then unskews the child, centering it and making it big enough to fill the skew's stick-out bits.

**HTML**

```
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="images/sad-kid.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.skewed {
  position: relative;
  height: 140px;
  transform: skew(-2deg) rotate(2deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-2deg) rotate(2deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-2deg) rotate(2deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.skewed > * {
  width: 110%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: skew(2deg) rotate(-2deg) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: skew(2deg) rotate(-2deg) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: skew(2deg) rotate(-2deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

This is similar to Andy Hoffman's method, but supports a greater number of browsers.

Comment: What you've got was my first attempt. I chose a different way because I felt the skew/unskew method feels kind of dirty. But I guess you could say the same for the Polyfill. Eventually, `CSS` forces us to do bad things.